# Controlling event in timezone and days with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, actionscript

I have a flash site that I need to put in a page a list of the food menu, in this site will have 6 menu's of food, and each menu is for one week, in first week will have the first menu until the last week that is the six will have the sixt menu, than it will return in the beginning and starts again. Basically the menu's will make a loop in the weekends. I was told me that its better to do in Javascript since it looks like in `ActionScript` isn't possible, so I think i'll export the info of a html page to a `swf`.

My question is how can I control in Javascript a event  of a object whit my time zone and days, can someone give me a idea or guide me to a tutorial in the web that explains  what im looking for?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a `Date` object that returns the time based on the user's clock, so the timezone will already be set to their local time.

Docs for the `Date` object: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Some noteworthy methods of the `Date` object:

- getTimezoneOffset() - Returns the time difference between GMT and local time, in minutes
- getTime() - Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1, 1970

If you want to show/hide content based on what week it is in the year, you can setup a `getWeek()` method:

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
    var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(),0,1);
    return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()+1)/7);
}
```

Usage:

```
var today = new Date();
var weekno = today.getWeek();
```